# FatalErrorException in Laravel: Undefined constant

Tags: laravel

The code worked fine and also shows output, but the following error prevents it from completing the request:

> FatalErrorException in 9b9fbc933495f4e600f4e966ba91c292539fe032.php line 12:
>   Undefined class constant 'close'

[image]

Where might the problem be?

This is the compiled view:

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<h2>Upload File Here</h2>

<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => '/handleUpload','files' => true)); ?>

    <?php echo Form::file('file'); ?>

    <?php echo Form::token(); ?>

    <?php echo Form::submit('Upload'); ?>

<?php echo Form::close; ?>

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

And these are the original template files:

*views/layouts/master.blade.php*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel Upload Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*views/files/upload.blade.php*:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<h2>Upload File Here</h2>

{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/handleUpload','files' => true)) !!}
    {!! Form::file('file') !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}
{!! Form::close !!}
@endsection
```

Comment: Post related code from `9b9....32.php` file please. The file is in the `storage/framework/views/` directory.

Comment: provide your blade

Comment: @Rock thanks. I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `close` in a view instead of [`close()`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form). Do this:

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the last line below: `close` is a method, not a constant.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/handleUpload','files' => true)) !!}
    {!! Form::file('file') !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```